# Extract a specific line from a webpage using JSoup for Java

Tags: java, screen-scraping, web-scraping, jsoup

Hi I want to scrape some text from a website using the JSoup library. I have tried the following code, and that gives me the whole webpage, I want to just extract a specific line. Here is the code I am using:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
String text = doc.html();

System.out.println(text);
```

That prints out the following

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  Martin,James,28,London,20k
  <br /> Sarah,Jackson,43,Glasgow,32k
  <br /> Alex,Cook,22,Liverpool,18k
  <br /> Jessica,Adams,34,London,27k
  <br /> 
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I extract just the 6th line that reads `Alex,Cook,22,Liverpool,18k` and put it into an array where each element is a word before a comma (eg: [0] = Alex, [1] = Cook, etc)

Comment: Do you have control of the target website?  If so, then can you change the html output to make it easier to capture this data?

Comment: @Shane I have no control of the website unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to format (?) the Result a bit:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
    int count = 0; // Count Nodes

    for( Node n : doc.body().childNodes() )
    {
        if( n instanceof TextNode )
        {
            if( count == 2 ) // Node 'Alex'
            {
                String t[] = n.toString().split(","); // you have an array with each word as string now

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t)); // eg. output
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[ Alex, Cook, 22, Liverpool, 18k ]
```

### Edit:

Since you cant select `TextNode`'s by its ccntent (only possible with `Element`s) you need a small workaround:

```
for( Node n : doc.body().childNodes() )
{
    if( n instanceof TextNode )
    {
        str = n.toString().trim();

        if( str.toLowerCase().startsWith("alex") ) // Node 'Alex'
        {
            String t[] = n.toString().split(","); // you have an array with each word as string now

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t)); // eg. output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, just one more thing, sometimes the content slightly changes on the website, so is it possible to get the line that begins with Alex rather than the line that is 6th?

Comment: I have added another solution (see Edit) - not the most elegant one but it works.